# 9 Bleeps Installing new GPU - Black Screen

Tags: power-supply, gpu, amd-radeon

1. BIOSTAR TH55B HD
2. Intel i5 760
3. 2 x 4gb ddr 3 ram
4. 600W PSU
5. 1TB Samsung HD105SI
6. ATApi iHAS124 CD/DVD
7. Windows XP

I am trying to install my new msi radeon r6950 twin frozr iii

However when I install it and turn my pc on it makes 9 bleeps and black screen, no signal.

It seems to power up fine. I have connected one pin to it.

Before installing the new GPU I uninstalled my old Nvidia Drivers.

I haven't done this before but I have watched a lot of videos and read guides. I am completely stuck.

Comment: Have you tried reseating the video card?

Comment: these long, short, or a combination? 9 beeps indicating something isn't installed right.

Comment: I don't know how to reset a video card, <edit> but I did try taking it out and putting it back in quite a few times.. Upon googling reset graphics card it seems I done it by accident. The first beep is somewhat long the rest are very quick

Comment: You need to **reseat** the card not **reset** it.  You did what exactly by accident?  What does the manual for your motherboard say the beep code means?

Comment: Thats what I done

Comment: FYI:  Every BIOSTAR motherboard I have ever helped people with has been a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

BioStar's beep codes are listed here:

http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/support/faq_content.php?S_ID=401

The closest thing looks like a video adapter issue.  One thing I would recommend is resetting the CMOS on your motherboard in case there is a bad setting conflicting with the new adapter.  If this doesn't clear the error, remove all other adapter cards and just boot CPU, RAM and Video.  That particular card requires a 500W power supply minimum so if you are running other high wattage hardware this may be causing the video card to not receive enough power.  I would recommend testing another lower wattage video adapter if your problems persist to see if it is a power issue if all else fails.